# Strange input error, I have used this code before

Tags: java, eof, objectinputstream

After a very bad attempt at doing my *homework*, I decided it would be faster to abandon everything and start from scratch. Well not everything ... I copied this part since it worked perfectly so I saw no need to modify it. While maybe not perfect, it worked.

**However** now, when I compile just to test it out, I get an unexpected error:

`Input error: java.io.EOFException`.

Notice that "Input error" is from my `catch(IOException ioe)`.

The file (`fileName`) is completely empty. Nothing in it. What could cause this. Is there a way to tell the `ObjectInputStream` to do nothing if the file is empty ?

**Also** I tested this out with an empty file on my other "iteration", didn't have this problem. I even named my file the same.

```
public Repository (String fileName) throws  FileNotFoundException,
                                            IOException,
                                            SecurityException,
                                            ClassNotFoundException {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.clients = new ArrayList<Client> ();

    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;

    try {
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(this.fileName);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        this.clients = (ArrayList<Client>) in.readObject();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found, error: " + fnfe);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Input error: " + ioe);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("Class not found, error: " + cnfe);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        System.out.println(
                       "You do not have permission to access this file, error: " 
                       + se);
    } finally {
        if (fileIn != null)
            fileIn.close();
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely before

```
    in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    this.clients = (ArrayList<Client>) in.readObject();
```

you want to check the file size via [File.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29).

I assume if it's empty then you'd want to return an empty array list. You can't do that via deserialising an empty file. After all, even an empty array list has a non-zero size (and would need to identify itself as an array list via serialised attributes)

Comment: Is it possible if I have several spaces, but still no "text" / data, that `File.length()` would still not be enough ? Also. How do I get file ?. Honestly I only know how to open a File Input / Output Stream

Comment: If your file does not contain a valid object serialisation (and that includes having 'spaces' etc.) then you're going to get an exception very quickly. A serialised object file isn't robust in the face of additional invalid data

Comment: Ok, how do I use the File.length() then, how do I get the file. Honestly I only know how to use the File Input / Output stream.

Answer (score 1):

> The file (fileName) is completely empty. Nothing in it.

That's exactly the problem. You cannot read an object (or an array) from an empty file. It will not find any data and throw an End-of-file-Exception (EOFException).

Even an empty array - when serialized to a file - will produce some data because the object stream will write the type (ArrayList) and the size of the array (0) to the file. When you try to read it, it will expect to find this data.